# What is the cause of this problem while pub get in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

error on android studio flutter

C:\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get
Resolving dependencies...

```
Because every version of youtube_player_iframe from path depends on webview_flutter ^4.0.2 and fstore depends on webview_flutter 3.0.4, youtube_player_iframe from path is forbidden.
```

So, because fstore depends on youtube_player_iframe from path, version solving failed.

The Flutter CLI developer tool uses Google Analytics to report usage and diagnostic
data along with package dependencies, and crash reporting to send basic crash
reports. This data is used to help improve the Dart platform, Flutter framework,
and related tools.

[Please check this error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiQkI.png)